# How is it possible to access a functions variable outside the function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been told at my university that everything is put on the top of the "stack" when working with a function. So, when returning from one, the top of the stack is removed, until we reach the bottom - main(). Suggesting that everything is lost we have made in the local scope of the previous functions.

Most books tell me the same thing.

However, i have come across a number of occurrences, where i used this exact feature.

For instance:

```
void address (bool** xpp)
{
    bool* y = (bool*) malloc(10*sizeof(bool));
    y[2] = false;
    **xpp = &y;
}

int main(void)
{
    bool* x;
    bool** xp = &x;

    address(&xp);
    xp[0] = false;
    xp[2] = false;
    xp[7] = false;

    printf("%d", xp[0]);
    printf("%d", xp[2]);
    printf("%d", xp[7]);

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, to my understanding, i should not be able to refer to the xp[] array in the main() after address(), because, indeed i have set it's pointer to an arrays first elements pointer, but after returning to main() the array i had created in address() is supposed to be gone. So it should be pointing to nowhere and should pop up an exception.

However, all of the bool xp elements print '0', implying it's success in working.

Comment: You can write instead of this `bool* y = (bool*) malloc(10*sizeof(bool));` in the function, the following `*xpp = (bool*) malloc(10*sizeof(bool));` or just instead of the last line `**xpp = &y;`, this `*xpp = y;`

Comment: The code provokes undefined behaviour, yes. But this assumption "*should pop up an exception*" is just one possibility to which undefined behaviour may lead. In fact anything may happen, from nothing to crash to ... C does not provide any hidden error checking.

Comment: `address(&xp);` is a constraint violation. You should get a compilation error on that line. If you don't then you need to adjust your compiler settings.

Comment: I especially don't understand the line `**xpp = &y`.  On the right-hand side, `y` is a pointer-to-bool, so `&y` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-bool.  On the left-hand side, `xpp` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-bool, so `**xpp` is a bool.  So you're taking a pointer-to-pointer-to-bool, and assigning it to a bool.  That makes no sense, and the compiler should have complained about it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two different answers here.  Your question boils down to, "I heard that local variables are lost when they're popped from the stack, but I tried it, and they were still there", but your actual code does *not* demonstrate the use of local variables on the stack that would be lost; it demonstrates the use of `malloc`, which is completely different.

And then the second answer is, any time you ask *anything* like "I heard that X doesn't work, but I tried it, and it worked", you're playing with fire: it might have *seemed* to have worked, but it wasn't guaranteed to.

Let's look at a slightly different version of your program.  Instead of playing with pointers to pointers, I'm just going to have the `address` function return a pointer to the first element of an array.  And instead of an array of bools, I'm going to use an array of `int`, so I can more easily show interesting numbers.  Here's the first version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *address()
{
    int *p = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    if(p == NULL) abort();
    p[0] = 1; p[1] = 2; p[2] = 3; p[3] = 4; p[4] = 5;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int *a = address();
    int i, sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) sum += a[i];
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

Function `address` returns a pointer, but it's a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory, which is guaranteed to stick around even after `address` returns.  The program prints

```
sum = 15
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 4
a[4] = 5
```

which is just what you would expect.

But now let's change function `address` to not call `malloc`, but instead, use a local array:

```
int *address()
{
    int la[5];
    la[0] = 1; la[1] = 2; la[2] = 3; la[3] = 4; la[4] = 5;
    return la;
}
```

This function is broken.  It returns a pointer to the first element of a local array.  By the time the function returns to its caller, that array will no longer exist.  The pointer can never be useful to its caller; it is virtually guaranteed not to work.  Indeed, when I compile this second version, my compiler warns me about it:

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'a' returned
```

But if Ignore that warning and run the resulting program anyway, here's what I get:

```
sum = 15
a[0] = 507402241
a[1] = -16764064
a[2] = 0
a[3] = 0
a[4] = 0
```

This is a very interesting result.  The second thing to notice is that the contents of the array are all wrong.  We don't see `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`; we see some numbers that are clearly garbage.  But this was to be expected, because that array `la` in function `address` is gone.

But the first and perhaps more interesting thing to notice is that *the sum is correct!*  How did *that* happen?  And the sum doesn't match the contents of the array as printed!  It's as if the "broken" pointer returned by the `address` function worked for a little while, just long enough to compute the "correct" sum, but got trashed later.  And, in fact, that's exactly what happened.

After function `address` returns, the array `la` is "gone", but the memory on the stack that it was using hasn't been reused or erased yet, so the bit patterns are still there.  So the calling function, `main`, can try to access those bits, and it even seems to get the right answer -- it computes the same sum, 15.  It's important to note that this is absolutely *not* guaranteed to work; you would *never* want to depend on it in a real program -- it just happens to work.

But then, having computed the sum, `main` calls `printf` to print it out.  And `printf` is a function that gets called -- a big, complicated function -- and it does all sorts of stuff, and allocates all sorts of its own variables on the stack.  So that's when the stack memory that had been allocated to the `la` array actually gets overwritten.  So that's why, when the last half of the `main` function tries to print out the array, it's garbage.

There's another point to make and that has to do with addresses.  When we worry about the local array `la` getting lost or not, there are two questions to ask: do we lose the contents of the array, and, do we lose the pointer to the array?  And in answering those questions, we encounter a significant fact: a function can still, perfectly well, return a value, even though the function's local (stack) storage has gone away.

To see this, consider the function

```
int five()
{
    int r = 5;
    return r;
}
```

When function `five` returns, its local variable `r` goes away.  But the caller who says

```
int x = five();
```

has no problem, because as function `five` returns, and even as function `five`s local variable `r` is being allocated, the return value 5 is being copied into the caller's own variable `x`, so it's not lost.

---

But with all of that said -- and besides the question of whether the array is a local (stack) array or allocated with `malloc` -- there's also something wrong, sort of differently wrong, with he way you're taking `y`'s address.  `y` is a local variable, so after the function exits, `&y` is bogus, and not guaranteed to work, no matter where you've stashed it.  (But, again, it might seem to work, for a little while, until something else overwrites the stack.)

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible to access a functions variable outside the function?

Assuming it's not declared `static` you simply cannot, for the reason you mentioned: It's gone the moment the function had been left.

> after returning to main() the array i had created in address() is supposed to be gone.

The call to `malloc` did not create a "variable", but it allocated memory from the heap. All that is stored locally inside the function's variable `y` is the *address* of this very block of memory. This address indeed is lost when `y` goes away by leaving the function.

To not lose the address of the memory allocated fix the code for example like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf() */

void address (bool** xpp)
{
  bool* y = malloc(10*sizeof(bool));
  y[2] = false;
  *xpp = y;
}

int main(void)
{
  bool* xp;

  address(&xp);
  xp[0] = false;
  xp[2] = false;
  xp[7] = false;

  printf("%d", xp[0]);
  printf("%d", xp[2]);
  printf("%d", xp[7]);

  return 0;
}
```

A major flaw still with this code is, that the caller (`main`) and the callee (`address`) do not "talk" about how much memory has to be/was allocate.

Comment: So the allocated memory is left intact, but the address is "forgotten"?

Comment: @JohnDale the paper on which the address was first written was trashed :D

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything about this code is misleading.

The question is, "How can the `xp` pointer be valid after function `address` returns?  But it turns out that the call to `address` does not modify the `xp` pointer.

`xp` is set to point to `x`.  The call to `address` doesn't change that.  (The call to `address` does end up changing what `xp` points to, that is, it changes `x`.

Although `xp` is not a pointer to bool, it's used as if it were, in the three assignments

```
xp[0] = false;
xp[2] = false;
xp[7] = false;
```

Although `xp` doesn't actually point to memory that's been allocated to hold 10 bools, wherever it does point (that is, somewhere on the stack surrounding `x`), there's evidently enough memory to accidentally store 10 bools without causing too much damage.

And then, having stored a few bools at wherever-it-is, trying to print those three bools back out (from wherever-it-was) happens to work.

For answers to the question of how the local storage in a function can still be accessed (though incorrectly) after the function returns -- and although this code doesn't actually end up doing that -- see my other answer.

For the record, there are other problems.  The call

```
address(&xp);
```

is a type mismatch (`&xpp` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to-bool, but `address()` accepts a pointer-to-pointer-to-bool).  The line

```
 **xpp = &y;
```

is a type mismatch (`&y` is a pointer-to-pointer-to=-bool, but `**xpp` is a bool).  Lines like

```
xp[0] = false;
```

are a type mismatch (`false` is a bool, but `xp[0]` is a pointer-to-bool).  Finally, lines like

```
printf("%d", xp[0]);
```

are a type mismatch (`xp[0]` is a pointer-tobool, but `%d` expects an int, or maybe a bool).